# 2 identical VPS (Ubuntu 18.04): Postfix - Alerts from Monit to Google mail is not working

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server, ubuntu-18.04, monit

Let's start from beginning. I have a two identical VPS servers with Ubuntu 18.04 OS and Monit installed on both. I configured mailserver on the monit (for sending alerts) configuration as a localhost on both. The problem is that on one server everything works fine and on another i receive an error: NOQUEUE: reject: **RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table**

I did not configured Dovecot and Postfix specially, so it should work both on default configurations. I have compared Working postfix server and not working postfix server config's and it seems that they are more or less the same. Here they are:

Working Server:

```
    # See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = sub.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, sub.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, , localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = may
allow_percent_hack = no
```

and on this server everything just works fine without configuring anything more, just putting localhost as a mailserver in the monit config.

Not working server:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.cert.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/postfix.key.pem
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = sub2.domain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, sub2.domain.com, localhost.domain.com, ,localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtp_tls_security_level = dane
allow_percent_hack = no
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/postfix.ca.pem
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = !SSLv2, !SSLv3, !TLSv1, !TLSv1.1
```

This server generates upper mentioned error.

Destination mail has a different domain than a these servers and mailbox is in the google. After checking nslookup NX, seems that it's solved correctly:

```
Non-authoritative answer:
maildomain.com  mail exchanger = 5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
maildomain.com  mail exchanger = 10 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
maildomain.com  mail exchanger = 10 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
maildomain.com  mail exchanger = 5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
maildomain.com  mail exchanger = 1 aspmx.l.google.com.
```

One more thing is that on the not working server there is apache with configured website maildomain.com and i think maybe its makes confuse a server to sent email. Maybe its looking only mail address locally and then receives this error: **RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in virtual alias table**

Any ideas how to make it work and what here could be bad would be perfect. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid I cannot comment yet, so this has to be an answer...

It seems postfix can not find the user in its local database, so the user does not seem to be a local user and the user does not seem to be in the /etc/aliases file. Or, and you should try this. You have not run the newaliases command.

For further help it would be useful to provide a little more info:

- Recepient of the email
- Contents of the respective /etc/aliases files